# RPC C++ server side dynamic endpoint

Tags: c++, server, rpc

I'm doing a rpc server/client project. The hardcoded endpoint version works well and now I want to let the server to dynamically setup the endpoint.

I did some research, and I need to use `RpcNsBindingExport()` function to export the name service database for server, then client can get the available binding information. Server code can compile but there is a error when I run the server. The error message says that: 
***LNK2019  unresolved external symbol __imp__RpcNsBindingExportA@20 referenced in function _main***

Here is the code for my server.cpp:

```
main(){
    //choose protocol sequence
    status = RpcServerUseProtseq(
        pszProtocolSequence,
        RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,
        pszSecurity
    );
    if (status) exit(status);

    //get binding info for server
    RPC_BINDING_VECTOR *binding_vector;
    status = RpcServerInqBindings(&binding_vector);

    //Export to a name service database for advertising
    status = RpcNsBindingExport(
        RPC_C_NS_SYNTAX_DEFAULT,
        (unsigned char *)"hostname",
        midl_v1_0_s_ifspec,
        binding_vector,
        NULL
    );

    if (status) exit(status);

    //reg server
    status = RpcEpRegister(
        hello_v1_0_s_ifspec,
        binding_vector,
        NULL,
        (unsigned char *)annotion
    );

    //listen
    if (status) exit(status);

    status = RpcServerListen(cMinCalls,
        RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,
        fDontWait);

    if (status) exit(status);
}
```

Both rpcrt4.lib and rpcns4.lib are linked in the project. I don't know if there is anything missing, or maybe the usage of the `RpcNsBindingExport()` is wrong.

Thanks for any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. In particular there is no `main` in the code you show, but that seems to be where the error is

Comment: you say "error when I run the server" but the error is a linker error...

Comment: "_I don't know if there is anything missing, or maybe the usage of the `RpcNsBindingExport()` is wrong_" Such error (_unresolved external symbol_) on a library function call, most commonly is caused by not linking against said library (.lib), where the function is defined, not because of some weird usage of it (if it were - you would get compilation error, not linking error). Please elaborate on what do you mean by "_Both rpcrt4.lib and rpcns4.lib are **included** in the project._" (what do you mean by the word "included"?).

Comment: From the MSDN documentation: _Note  This function is not supported on Windows Vista and later operating systems._ Maybe the libs don't contain the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Error **LNK2019 unresolved external symbol** happens when the compiler cannot find the lib file. Try to put the full path of the .lib files in the **Additional dependencies** under linker drop down. And Check for build option (x32 or x64). The x32 lib cannot work with x64 application or else.

Comment: The rpcns4.lib is x32 lib, but my build option is X64. I changed it to x32 and it works now. Thanks for pointing it out.